# Set table's height to its parent div's height whose height is variable

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I have a table inside a div, which contains an image with "position:absolute", "width:100%" and "height:auto". The div has a variable height, and I need the table to have the same height as the div, so the cells can have percentage heights...

It also would help if I found the way for the div, or a table, to adapt to the height of the image when it is a background-image. Because when I set the width as 100%, the image doesn't show full vertically, only horizontal and gets cut by the size of the table/div.

```css
#footer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <img src="All/footer.png" style="position:absolute; width:100%">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="height:30%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10%;"></td>
      <td id="content" style="width:40%; height:30%;">ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph
        <br/>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph
        <br/>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph
        <br/>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph
        <br/>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph</td>
      <td style="width:50%;"></td>
      <td rowspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height:25%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="slogan" colspan="3" style="height:10%">One Line Text. Slogan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="height:10%;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you already achieve or give us a jsfiddle

Comment: I don't think what you want used to be possible before flex-box without JavaScript. However, it may be in supporting browsers now. Checkout https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632570/how-to-have-html-tables-height-height-of-parent-div-when-divs-height-is-not?rq=1

Comment: Hi Isabel (a guess) - it would be really helpful if you could post the html code you have created, including any css / inline styling. That way people here on SO stand a better change of understanding what you want and of being able to help you.

Comment: @Paulie_D is right, that other question is the same I have,i couldn't found it before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have html table's height = height of parent div when div's height is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632570/how-to-have-html-tables-height-height-of-parent-div-when-divs-height-is-not)